# Disabling Tabs in Master Page for specfic views

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

It is the first time for me to use Master Page layout.

At the moment I have 3 tabs in the menu: Login/Add/Edit

I would like to have only one tab visible on the Login page (default page) and after login is successful the Login tab is disabled (because user is already logged in) and Add/Edit tabs are enabled.

```
<asp:Menu ID="LoginMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Login" NavigateUrl="login.aspx" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" NavigateUrl="add.aspx" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" NavigateUrl="edit.aspx" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% if(LoggedIn){ %>   //Here you should check if the user has logged in I just used LoggedIn variable as example.
<asp:Menu ID="LoginMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Login" NavigateUrl="login.aspx" />
                      </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
<%} else{%>
<asp:Menu ID="LoginMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Logout" NavigateUrl="logout.aspx" />
                      </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
<%}%>
```

Edit:

or you can just set `Enabled="False"` in the else part, or just remove the else.

Comment: I am kinda looking for something like this:
if url=login.aspx {
display menu1
}else{
display menu 2
}

Comment: context codes (<% %>) wo'nt work inside runat="server" tags so you should use it like this. otherwise you could use it like: `<a href="<%loggedin?"logout":"login"%>.aspx"><%loggedin?"logout":"login"%></a>`

Comment: what about that LoggedIn function, how do I write this? I only know vb, not used to this language

Comment: well I started my programming with vb ;) use like: `<a href="<%=iif(loggedin,"logout","login")%>.aspx"><%=iif(loggedin,"logout","login")%></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Web.sitemap and Filtering Site-Map Nodes Based on Security Roles.

something like that:

**.aspx**

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"  runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
</asp:Menu>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

**Web.sitemap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
<siteMapNode url="~/login.aspx" title="Login"  description="Login">
        <siteMapNode url="~/loggedin/add.aspx" title="Add"  description="Add" />
         <siteMapNode url="~/loggedin/edit.aspx" title="Edit"  description="Edit" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

**sample web.config for "loggedin" direcrory**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="AcceptedUserRole" />
            <allow roles="AdministratorRole" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

for detailed explanation check the [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)